# ImportError: No module named grid_search, learning_curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

Problem with Scikit learn l can't use learning_curve of Sklearn and `sklearn.grid_search`.

When l do `import sklearn` (it works) `from sklearn.cluster import bicluster` (it works). i try to reinstall scikit-learn also remain the same issue. I am using python 3.5.6, Scikit-learn version 0.20.0 Window 10.

```
 import sklearn
 from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score, 
 train_test_split 
 from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
 from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**In the new version these are in the `model_selection` module.**

Use this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve, GridSearchCV
```